# recursive merge sort in python

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to make merge sort using two functions in python. But I got an error like
**IndexError: list assignment index out of range** whenever run my code. I don't know which part is wrong.
This is my code below. 
Any help will appreciate!!

```
def merge(A):

    def merge_sort(A,first,last):
        if first<last:
            mid=(first+last)//2
            merge_sort(A,first, mid)
            merge_sort(A,mid+1,last)

            temp=[]
            temp.append(99999)
            i=first
            j=mid+1
            k=0
            while i<=mid and j<=last:
                if A[i]<=A[j]:
                    temp[k]=A[i]
                    k=k+1
                    i=i+1
                else:
                    temp[k]=A[j]
                    k=k+1
                    j=j+1
            while i<=mid:
                temp[k]=A[i]
                k=k+1
                i=i+1
            while j<=last:
                temp[k]=A[j]
                k=k+1
                j=j+1
            a=0
            b=first
            while a<k:
                A[b]=temp[a]
                b=b+1
                a=a+1

    merge_sort(A,0,len(A)-1)

    return A
```

Comment: usually the full error stack provides the line number where the error/exception occurs, maybe you can share that, or it might even provide you the answer you are looking for. additionally "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" should give you a pretty good idea of where to look...

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign a value to `temp[k]` as long as this element does not exist.

Delete the row `temp.append(99999)`, replace every `temp[k]=A[i]` by `temp.append(A[i])` and every `temp[k]=A[j]` by `temp.append(A[j])`.

You will end up with:

```
def merge(A):

    def merge_sort(A,first,last):
        if first<last:
            mid=(first+last)//2
            merge_sort(A,first, mid)
            merge_sort(A,mid+1,last)

            temp=[]
            i=first
            j=mid+1
            k=0
            while i<=mid and j<=last:
                if A[i]<=A[j]:
                    temp.append(A[i])
                    k=k+1
                    i=i+1
                else:
                    temp.append(A[j])
                    k=k+1
                    j=j+1
            while i<=mid:
                temp.append(A[i])
                k=k+1
                i=i+1
            while j<=last:
                temp.append(A[j])
                k=k+1
                j=j+1
            a=0
            b=first
            while a<k:
                A[b]=temp[a]
                b=b+1
                a=a+1

    merge_sort(A,0,len(A)-1)

    return A


A = [1,9,4,5]
print(A)
print(merge(A))
```

Output:

```
[1, 9, 4, 5]
[1, 4, 5, 9]
```